# SearchView in Not Working in Recycler View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit, searchview

I'm trying to add searchview on recyclerview but its not working even not showing any error. I ready many answers on stackoverflow but they are not worked for me.please tell me what is mistake in my code. when i debug my code then searched values are showing in result variable but not showing in recyclerview. i want to search with 1) Country Name 2) capital 3) and id can some help me

**my adapter is here**

```
class ProfileListAdapter(var profiles:ArrayList<Profile>):RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileListAdapter.ProfileViewHolder>(),Filterable {

   
    fun updateProfile(newProfiles:List<Profile>){
        profiles.clear()
        profiles.addAll(newProfiles)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    var profileFilterList = ArrayList<Profile>()
    init {
        profileFilterList = profiles
    }
    class ProfileViewHolder(view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
       private var id = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_id)
       private var name = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_name)
       private var fatherName = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_father_name)
       private var profileImage = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_profile_image)
       private var progressDrawable = getProgressDrawable(view.context)

       fun bind(profile: Profile){
          id.text = profile.id.toString()
           name.text = profile.name
           fatherName.text = profile.fatherName
           profileImage.loadImage(profile.profilePicture,progressDrawable)
       }
   }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = ProfileViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.rv_dummy_items,parent,false)
    )
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProfileViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(profiles[position])
    }
    override fun getItemCount() = profiles.size


// Search items
    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
                val charString = constraint?.toString() ?: ""
                if (charString.isEmpty()){
                    profiles.also { profileFilterList = it }
                } else {
                    val filteredList = ArrayList<Profile>()
                    profiles
                        .filter {
                            (it.name.contains(constraint!!)) or (it.fatherName.contains(constraint))
                        }
                        .forEach { filteredList.add(it) }
                    profileFilterList = filteredList
                }
                return FilterResults().apply { values = profileFilterList }
            }
            override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
                profileFilterList = if (results?.values == null) ArrayList()
                else
                    results.values as ArrayList<Profile>
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    
}
```

**my main activity is here**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var viewModel: ListViewModel
    var profileAdapter = ProfileListAdapter(arrayListOf())

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        //here I'm calling search profile function
        searchProfile()
        //
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.refresh()

        binding.rvProfileList.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            adapter = profileAdapter
        }
        observeViewModel()
        filterButtons()
    }
    fun observeViewModel() {
        viewModel.profiles.observe(this, Observer { profiles: List<Profile>? ->
            profiles?.let {
                binding.rvProfileList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                profileAdapter.updateProfile(it)
            }
        })
        viewModel.profileLoadingError.observe(this, Observer { isError: Boolean? ->
            isError?.let {
                binding.listError.visibility = if (it) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            }
        })
        viewModel.loading.observe(this, Observer { isLoading ->
            isLoading?.let {
                binding.loadingView.visibility = if (it) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            }
        })

    }

    //search function
    fun searchProfile(){

        binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                profileAdapter.filter.filter(query)
                return false
            }
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                profileAdapter.filter.filter(newText)
                return false
            }

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your code quality is really bad. I read repeatly to understand what you mean.

Firstly, you are filtering twice in OnQueryTextListener. Instead you can filter once only. Change your searchProfile function to

```
 fun searchProfile(){

    binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }
        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            profileAdapter.filter.filter(newText)
            return false
        }

    })
}
```

Probably, your failure is because of reassigning your **profiles** and **profileFilterList** lists.

In few times, you are assingning **profiles** to **profileFilterList**, not copying! Both of two lists have same references. So if one of them changes, other list changes directly.

Change your Adapter init block from

```
init {
    profileFilterList = profiles
}
```

to

```
init {
    profileFilterList = ArrayList(profiles)
}
```

Change your getFilter function from

```
    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val charString = constraint?.toString() ?: ""
            if (charString.isEmpty()){
                profiles.also { profileFilterList = it }
            } else {
                val filteredList = ArrayList<Profile>()
                profiles
                    .filter {
                        (it.name.contains(constraint!!)) or (it.fatherName.contains(constraint))
                    }
                    .forEach { filteredList.add(it) }
                profileFilterList = filteredList
            }
            return FilterResults().apply { values = profileFilterList }
        }
        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            profileFilterList = if (results?.values == null) ArrayList()
            else
                results.values as ArrayList<Profile>
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val filteredList = mutableListOf<Profile>()

            if (constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) {
                filteredList.addAll(profiles)
            } else {
                filteredList.addAll(
                    profiles.filter { (it.name.contains(constraint!!)) or (it.fatherName.contains(constraint)) }                    )
            }

            return FilterResults().apply { values = filteredList }
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            profileFilterList.clear()
            results?.values?.let {
                profileFilterList.addAll(it as MutableList<Profile>)
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanku soo much sir for your answer. sir its still not working

Comment: Can you explain me what you mean with 'not working'?

Comment: means when i search for something, it doesn't search

Comment: After i submitted my answer, i modified a little bit. Can you try current codes?

Answer (score 0):

I edit in your adapter and filter works fine with me my code after modification

```
class ProfileListAdapter():RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileListAdapter.ProfileViewHolder>(),Filterable {
  
 var profileList: ArrayList<Profile> = ArrayList()
 var profileListFiltered: ArrayList<Profile> = ArrayList()


fun updateProfile(newProfiles:List<Profile>){
    
     profileList = ArrayList(newProfiles)
     profileListFiltered = profileList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

class ProfileViewHolder(view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
   private var id = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_id)
   private var name = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_name)
   private var fatherName = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_father_name)
   private var profileImage = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_profile_image)
   private var progressDrawable = getProgressDrawable(view.context)

   fun bind(profile: Profile){
      id.text = profile.id.toString()
       name.text = profile.name
       fatherName.text = profile.fatherName
       profileImage.loadImage(profile.profilePicture,progressDrawable)
   }
  }
     override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = 
    ProfileViewHolder(
    


LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.rv_dummy_items,parent,false)
)
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProfileViewHolder, position: Int) 
      {
           holder.bind(profileListFiltered[position])
        }
          override fun getItemCount() = profileListFiltered.size


         // Search items
        override fun getFilter(): Filter {
              return object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults 
           {
            val charString = constraint?.toString() ?: ""
            if (charString.isEmpty()){
               profileListFiltered = profileList
            } else {
                val filteredList = ArrayList<Profile>()
                profileList
                    .filter {
                        (it.name.contains(constraint!!)) or 
                  (it.fatherName.contains(constraint))
                    }
                    .forEach { filteredList.add(it) }
                profileFilterList = filteredList
            }
            return FilterResults().apply { values = profileFilterList }
        }
        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: 
    FilterResults?) {
            profileFilterList = if (results?.values == null) ArrayList()
            else
                results.values as ArrayList<Profile>
            notifyDataSetChanged()
          }
      }
    }


 }
```

in your activity just declare adapter without parameters constructor after get data using function inside adapter updateProfile then will work fine with you ISA

Edit for your adapter

```
class ProfileListAdapter(var 
    profiles:ArrayList<Profile>)
  :RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileListAdapter.Profile 
 ViewHolder>(),Filterable {


fun updateProfile(newProfiles:List<Profile>){
    profiles.clear()
    profiles.addAll(newProfiles)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
var profileFilterList = ArrayList<Profile>()
init {
    profileFilterList = profiles
}
class ProfileViewHolder(view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
   private var id = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_id)
   private var name = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_name)
   private var fatherName = view.findViewById<TextView> 
    (R.id.tv_father_name)
   private var profileImage = view.findViewById<ImageView> 
   (R.id.iv_profile_image)
   private var progressDrawable = getProgressDrawable(view.context)

   fun bind(profile: Profile){
      id.text = profile.id.toString()
       name.text = profile.name
       fatherName.text = profile.fatherName
       profileImage.loadImage(profile.profilePicture,progressDrawable)
   }
  }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = 
  ProfileViewHolder(
   LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
   .inflate(R.layout.rv_dummy_items,parent,false)
     )
      override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProfileViewHolder, position: 
      Int) 
   {
    holder.bind(profileFilterList[position])
    }
    override fun getItemCount() = profileFilterList.size


  // Search items
   override fun getFilter(): Filter {
      return object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): 
         FilterResults {
            val charString = constraint?.toString() ?: ""
            if (charString.isEmpty()){
               profileFilterList = profiles
            } else {
                val filteredList = ArrayList<Profile>()
                profiles
                    .filter {
                        (it.name.contains(constraint!!)) or 
          (it.fatherName.contains(constraint))
                    }
                    .forEach { filteredList.add(it) }
                profileFilterList = filteredList
            }
            return FilterResults().apply { values = profileFilterList }
        }
        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: 
     FilterResults?) {
            profileFilterList = if (results?.values == null) ArrayList()
            else
                results.values as ArrayList<Profile>
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
    }


  }
```

Comment: if i remove this line: profiles.addAll(newProfiles) then list not shown and if i add this then search not working

Comment: this is adapter work work with you ?@faizdev

Comment: @faizdev No there is problem for your adapter you uses profiles list to bind with view and return count for it you must use profileFilterList in your adapter and return count from this list just try it will work with you  i think but i try my adapter work with  me fine for filter

Comment: i cant understand can you please edit my code?

Comment: without searchview this adapter is work fine for me

Comment: yes if using searchView doesn't work
Are you try my adapter ????

Comment: yes, but after trying your adapter list of profile are not shown

Comment: @faizdev your adapter I edit in my answer and I try it in my solution work fine with me